# Assign an ID for unique timestamp Pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I have a dataframe like this with thousands of rows. I would like to assign an ID for the each unique timestamp. How can i do this? Using map or is there any function like distinct? I have already separated and partitioned using window function so no need to do the differencing again. Just i need a unique id for each of the timestamp.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either **dense_rank(),rank()** window function on by ordering on `30_minutes_window` column to get unique ID for **same timestamp** value.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|         30_minutes|
#+-------------------+
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|
#|2005-12-24 05:30:00|
#|2005-12-24 05:30:00|
#+-------------------+

from pyspark.sql import *
w=Window.orderBy(col("30_minutes"))

df.withColumn("new_ID",dense_rank().over(w)).show()
#+-------------------+------+
#|         30_minutes|new_ID|
#+-------------------+------+
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|     1|
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|     1|
#|2005-12-23 05:30:00|     1|
#|2005-12-24 05:30:00|     2|
#|2005-12-24 05:30:00|     2|
#+-------------------+------+
```